# MYSQL documentation syntax grammar

Tags: mysql, sql, grammar

I can't seem to find, within the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html), a description of the syntax grammar they use throughout their site. This forces me into guessing, which for the most part works but others leaves me scratching my head.

Take this example. After reading the [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) I've come to the conclusion that the pipe `'|'` means OR, curley brackets `{...}` mean required and square brackets `[...]` mean optional. By that logic I could create a statement of `INSERT my_table (foo) VALUE (DEFAULT)` (notice the missing `INTO`) which doesn't seem right to me.

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Am I correct in thinking `INTO` is optional? And does anybody know where MySQL keep their page describing the syntax language they use?

I don't have access to a SQL server at the moment, so I can't test it until later.

Comment: Yep!  Seems `INTO` is, in fact, optional: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0abdd/1  You are 100% correct about how to interpret the syntax :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks for the fiddle link. That site is going to come in very useful :)

Comment: You're welcome! :-D  Yeah, SQLFiddle is pretty awesome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually exists in the docs, its called **1.2 Typographical and Syntax Conventions** and can be found here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/manual-conventions.html

Comment: I knew it had to be there somewhere.